Derivative of a loss function containing gaussians with respect to matrix
I am trying to reproduce a derivation I found in the paper "Metric Learning for Kernel Regression" by K.Q. Weinberger and G. Tesauro, could be found here.
So, in kernel regression one tries to approximate a function $f$ over a dataset $x$, $$y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon $$ by a weighted average over samples in the dataset,
$$ \hat{y_i} = \frac{\sum_{i \neq j } y_jk_{ij}}{\sum_{i \neq j }k_{ij}}$$
where the kernel $k$ is defined as
$$ k_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-\frac{d(x_i,x_j}{\sigma^2}}$$
(set $\sigma = 1$ in the sequel).
where $d(x_i,x_j) = \Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert ^2$, $A$ being a matrix.
A loss function is defined as
$$ \mathscr{L} = \sum_{i} (\hat{y_i} - y_i)^2  $$
and the goal is compute
$$ \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial A} $$
which in the paper is calculated as
$$ \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial A} = 4A \sum_{i} (\hat{y_i} - y_i) \sum_{j} (\hat{y_i} - y_i) k_{ij}(x_i - y_j)(x_i - y_j)^{T}$$.
I actually get stuck pretty quickly along the derivation.
So let us start by writing the loss function in full:
$$ \mathscr{L} = \sum_{i} \big(\frac{\sum_{i \neq j } y_jk_{ij}}{\sum_{i \neq j }k_{ij}} - y_i\big)^2 =  \sum_{i} \big(\frac{\sum_{i \neq j } y_j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-d(x_i,x_j)} }{\sum_{i \neq j }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-d(x_i,x_j)}} - y_i \big)^2 $$
one step further
$$ \mathscr{L} =   \sum_{i} \big(\frac{\sum_{i \neq j } y_j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-\Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert ^2} }{\sum_{i \neq j }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-\Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert ^2}} - y_i \big)^2 $$
Ok let me get one term of the summation, call it $\mathscr{L_i}$ and derive with respect to $A$.
Will use some shortcuts to facilitate notation
$$ E = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp^{-\Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert ^2} $$
and
$$ E_A = \frac{\partial E}{\partial A} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp^{-\Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert ^2} \Vert A(x_i-x_j\Vert $$
Using these
$$ \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_i}{\partial A} = 2 \big(\frac{\sum_{i \neq j} y_j E}{\sum_{i \neq j} E} \big) \frac{
\big( \sum_{i \neq j} y_j E_A (\sum_{i \neq j} E) \big) - \big(\sum_{i \neq j}E_A \sum_{i \neq j} y_j E \big)
}{(\sum_{i \neq j} E)^2 } $$
and frankly I get lost here, cannot see how to simplify those series multiplied to eaxh other, and proceed, any hints please, thanks

Stuff like this is best done using coordinate representation.
Starting with the inner most term, we have
$$\frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial A_{nm}} = -k_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} d(x_i,x_j) =  -k_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} \sum_{n',m'} (x_i-x_j)^T_{n'} (A^TA)_{n'm'} (x_i-x_j)_{m'}.$$
Now note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} (A^TA)_{n'm'} &= \sum_{l'} \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} A_{l'n'} A_{l'm'} \\
&= \sum_{l'} \left( \delta_{nl'} \delta_{mn'} A_{l'm'} + A_{l'n'} \delta_{nl'} \delta_{mm'} \right) = \delta_{mn'} A_{nm'} + \delta_{mm'} A_{nn'}.
\end{align}
Inserting this yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial k_{ij}}{\partial A_{nm}} &= -k_{ij} \sum_{n',m'} (x_i-x_j)^T_{n'} \left(\delta_{mn'} A_{nm'} + \delta_{mm'} A_{nn'}\right) (x_i-x_j)_{m'}\\
&=-k_{ij}\sum_{m'} (x_i-x_j)^T_{m} A_{nm'} (x_i-x_j)_{m'} - k_{ij} \sum_{n'} (x_i-x_j)^T_{n'} A_{nn'}(x_i-x_j)_{m}\\
&= -k_{ij}A_{nl} \sum_{l} (x_i-x_j)_{l} (x_i-x_j)^T_{m} - k_{ij} A_{nl} \sum_{l} (x_i-x_j)_{m} (x_i-x_j)^T_{l}\\
&= -k_{ij} (AX)_{nm}-k_{ij} (AX^T)_{nm} = -2k_{ij} (AX)_{nm}.
\end{align}
Here, the crucial insight is to define the matrix $X = (x_i-x_j) (x_i-x_j)^T$ (symmetric by construction, which is why the second term reduces to the first).
Now we just need to use the chain rule a bunch of times.
Starting from the outside,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} \mathcal{L} &= 2\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}}  (\hat{y}_i-y_i) = 2\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}}\frac{\sum_{j\neq i} y_jk_{ij}}{\sum_{j\neq i} k_{ij}}\\
&= 2\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}} \sum_{j\neq i} y_jk_{ij} + \sum_{j\neq i} y_jk_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{nm}}\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}}
\right]\\
&= -4\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j\neq i} y_jk_{ij}(AX)_{nm} - \sum_{l\neq i} y_lk_{il} \frac{1}{\left(\sum_{j\neq i} k_{ij}\right)^2} \sum_{j\neq i} k_{ij} (AX)_{nm}
\right]\\
&= -4\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j\neq i} y_jk_{ij}(AX)_{nm} - \frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j\neq i} \hat{y}_j k_{ij} (AX)_{nm}
\right]\\
&= 4\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j\neq i} (\hat{y}_j-y_j) k_{ij} (AX)_{nm}\\
&=  \sum_p 4A_{np}\sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j\neq i} (\hat{y}_j-y_j) k_{ij} X_{pm}.
\end{align}
Or, reverting back to matrix notation, this is just
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A} = 4A \sum_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)\frac{1}{\sum_{l\neq i} k_{il}} \sum_{j} (\hat{y}_j-y_j) k_{ij} (x_i-x_j) (x_i-x_j)^T.$$
This is almost what is claimed in the paper (note that we can include the term $j=i$ in the inner sum, as it is zero anyway), but I have no idea what happened to the additional sum over the weights in the denominator.
However, this is so close to the expected result that I doubt I made a major mistake. Maybe there is some normalization condition?

Thank you. Re: the last point, I think they might have just ignored any normalusing constant as it would be inconsequential dir the optimisation task.
